# Error:(22, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3]

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to ask my script error 22 gradle.  What is wrong with my script?

I'm trying to build a project but it keeps giving me this gradle error.  I have upgraded my gradle version to 3.3 and my android plugin version to 2.3.3 but it's still giving me the error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Error:

```
Error:(40, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()' Possible causes:

The project 'sms-mining-android' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project

The project 'sms-mining-android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

Event Log: Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

[image: Please include an image description here]

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softdev.weekimessenger"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you check your post with e.g. google translate?

Comment: Slight improvements made to English usage.  Presentation of error message improved by formatting it as a code sample.  Linked image made to appear in the body of the message by adding a `!` in front of the linking code - if you prefer it to appear as a link only then please include an image description in the link's code.

Answer (score 1):

The `implementation()` DSL requires **gradle v.4.x** and the **android plugin for gradle 3.x.**

More [info here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html).